# Question on linear perturbations in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, perturbation-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, dark-energy

I've been studying clustering dark energy when I came across a paper named "A Short Review on clustering dark energy" by Ronaldo Batista. there are 2 equations in this paper (eq.8 and eq.9) which I'm trying to derive:

$$
\begin{gather*}
\delta^{\prime}+3 \mathcal{H}(\delta p / \delta \rho-w) \delta+(1+w)\left(\theta-3 \Phi^{\prime}\right)=0  \tag{8}\\
\end{gather*}
$$

$$
\begin{gather*}
\theta^{\prime}+\mathcal{H}\left(1-3 c_{a}^{2}\right) \theta=k^{2} \Phi+\frac{\delta p / \delta \rho k^{2} \delta}{1+w} \tag{9}
\end{gather*}
$$

I started with the conservation of stress-energy tensor (like what the paper suggested):

$$\nabla^{v} \delta T_{v}^{\mu}=0$$

but I don't know how to perturb velocity terms inside the stress-energy tensor (I've tried to perturb gamma but it looked messy). I know how to derive these equations for different types of matter (dark matter, baryons,...) but I don't know how can I derive this equation which can hold for anything with an equation of state $w$.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is the paper. I didn't know if I could give the link or not: https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.12341